# Does Bayes' theorem have constraints for it to work?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am wondering if there's any situation where
$P(A|B)*P(B) ≠ P(B|A)*P(A)$ ???

I have a scenario, where I want to compute the similarity of two users. And these users can be described with a few features. Say $P(Us)$ represents two users' similarity and they have features $I$ and $T$. I can defined the probability that two users are similar (a.k.a. user similarity) as

$P(Us)=P(Is Ts)$, where $Is$ means two users are similar on $I$ feature and $Ts$ means two users are similar on $T$ feature.  So the more two users are similar in each of the two dimensions, the more the two users are similar.

So I calculated `P(Is|Ts)*P(Ts)` and `P(Ts|Is)P(Is)` in my scenario but they are not identical. It is a real scenario problem. Yes I know maybe that also depends on how the two ocnditional probabilities are defined in my case. But I am wondering if there's any constraints to make sure they have the identical result?

Comment: I don't really understand your situation but the Bayes theorem just compute $P(A|B)*P(B) =P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)*P(A)$ and always works. So you are probably computing something else if you do not get the same value.

Comment: I am also wondering whether Bayes' thorem matches my case or not..?

Comment: Your description is a bit strange. $P(U_s) = P(I_s \cap T_s)$ does not yet imply that $U_s = I_s \bigcap T_s$, which is needed to use Bayes' theorem.

Comment: Yes, this part needs consideration. My intuition is that if two users are more similar regarding both $I$ and $T$ features respectively, they are more similar. Does this have problem?

Comment: Questions related to how to best model some phenomenon might be better suited to stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

By **definition** for any event $B$ with positive probability
$$ P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B) $$

So if $A$ and $B$ have positive probability it is **always** true that 
$$ P(A|B) * P(B) = P(A \cap B) = P(B|A) * P(A) $$

Comment: The word **definition** might be a little misleading. $P(A|B)$ is defined as the probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ occurs. After that it is a logical deduction that multiplying this by probability of $B$ occurring should give the probability of both occurring.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on the definition. I took Kolmogorov's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event. Anyway, whatever the definition the property is true.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no constraints. Both sides of the equality

$$P(A|B)\times P(B) = P(B|A)\times P(A)$$

are always equal to $P(A\cap B)$.